# Like button doesn't show with javascript sdk , google analytics and like code

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, google-analytics-api

I'm using the javascript sdk in my application, and I would like to integrate the like button.

Here's my code :

```
 // javascript sfk to connect user and get infos
<script id="facebook-jssdk" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

<div onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Like', 'Clicked on Facebook Like Button']);" class="fb-like" data-href="https://url/id/fr" data-width="140px" data-height="27px" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-send="true"></div>
```

**Edit : My opengraph fields :**

- og:title,
- og:description,
- og:type,
- og:image,
- og:url,
- og:site_name,
- fb:admins,
- fb:app_id

  are filled correctly on my page

  and the faecbook debugging tolle
  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ says everything is fine
  Response Code 200**

The result is ... nothing :D

The code is on the page, but I don't have any like button !
I try to change it by css but nothing changed

I find an old article (2010) that says that you can't use facebook SDK and the like button code provide by facebook
http://allfacebook.com/one-problem-with-facebooks-new-like-button-it-doesnt-work-with-connect-sites_b13946

Or is it a probleme with my google analytic  onClick ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there a little trick inside the url to the facebook javscript SDK :
You have to specified #xfbml=1 to display like or share buttons.
in the javascript function the url should be :

js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js **#xfbml=1**";

Even if fbml and xfbml has been deprecated since june 2012.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/

And of, course, not a single line about it on the share button documentation.